# CAN communication on tms320f28377s using usbToCan driver with db9 connector

Tags: db9

I am using launchpad xl f28377s. It has a CAN transceiver which is intagreted. How can I connect this card to usbToCAN ixxat driver using db9 connector ?

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The D-Sub 9 connector on the Ixxat USB-to-CAN device has the following pin configuration ([manual](https://www.ixxat.com/docs/librariesprovider8/default-document-library/products/can-pc-interfaces/usb-to-can-v2-manual-english.pdf?sfvrsn=2)):

CAN High:   Pin 7

CAN Low:    Pin 2

GND (Ref): Pins 3 & 6

The F28377S LaunchPad has a header with three pins on one of its shorter sides with labels "CAN-H", "CAN-L", and "PGND". Connect these pins to the corresponding pins on the D-Sub 9 connector. This can be done with a female D-Sub 9 header ([example](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/crimp-d-sub-connectors/0481099/)).